# how to i get position when clicked object or sprite in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

> i'm not good at javascript... T_T
>
> can i get position(x,y,z) where i clicked sprite (or object) ?????
>
> below my code.. help me!!

---

```
    //sprite 
    var spriteMap = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'tag.png' );    
    var spriteMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { map: spriteMap, color: 0xffffff } );
    var sprite = new THREE.Sprite( spriteMaterial );
    sprite.scale.set(3, 3, 1)
    sprite.position.set(25, 20, 20)
    scene.add( sprite );
    objects.push(sprite);

    //sprite( text )
        var spritey = makeTextSprite( " spritey ", 
            { fontsize: 24, borderColor: {r:255, g:0, b:0, a:1.0}, backgroundColor: {r:255, g:100, b:100, a:1.0} } );
        spritey.position.set(-85,105,55);
        scene.add( spritey );
        console.log(makeTextSprite);
        objects.push(spritey);

    ///////////////////skip some codes//////////////////////////////////

    function onDocumentMouseUp(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var vector = new THREE.Vector3((event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2-1, -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1, 0.5);
        projector.unprojectVector(vector, camera);
        var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position, vector.sub(camera.position).normalize());
        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects);
        if (intersects.length > 0) {
            window.open(intersects[0].object.userData.URL);
            console.log(intersects.length)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want the position where you clicked:

```
var position = intersects[0].point
```

if you want the position of the object:

```
 var position = intersects[0].object.position
```